# Datagrid navigate link open in new tab

Tags: orocrm, orocommerce

Is it possible to configure datagrid navigate link to open in a new browser tab?

```
actions:
    view:
        type:          navigate
        label:         oro.grid.action.view
        link:          view_link
        icon:          eye
        acl_resource:  oro_user_user_view
        rowAction:     true
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NavigationAction` supports only inner navigation.
https://github.com/oroinc/platform/blob/master/src/Oro/Bundle/DataGridBundle/Resources/public/js/datagrid/action/navigate-action.js#L60-L91

But you can create own `CustomNavigationAction` and implement functionality that you need. Just remember, to get properly mapped from type `type: custom-navigation` , the module needs an alias with following structure `'oro/datagrid/action/{{type}}-action'`:

```yaml
aliases:
    oro/datagrid/action/custom-navigation$: acme/js/datagrid/action/custom-navigation-action

dynamic-imports:
    orodatagrid:
        - oro/datagrid/action/custom-navigation
```

see mapper https://github.com/oroinc/platform/blob/master/src/Oro/Bundle/DataGridBundle/Resources/public/js/map-action-module-name.js#L4

Comment: I guess information like this should be added to Oro documentation